# can't build c++ project with protobuf@24.2 in mac m2max

Tags: macos, protocol-buffers, homebrew, arm64

use brew install protobuf@24.2 and depend abseil@20230802, use cmake build with c++ project，but it not work.

build error log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<void const*, void const*>(void const*, void const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<haomo::msg::ProtoFile const*, haomo::msg::ProtoFile*>(haomo::msg::ProtoFile const* const&, haomo::msg::ProtoFile* const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<haomo::msg::DataType const*, haomo::msg::DataType*>(haomo::msg::DataType const* const&, haomo::msg::DataType* const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<haomo::msg::ProtoFileDes const*, haomo::msg::ProtoFileDes*>(haomo::msg::ProtoFileDes const* const&, haomo::msg::ProtoFileDes* const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase const*, google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase*>(google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase const* const&, google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase* const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<long long, long long>(long long, long long, char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_GEImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_GTImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::Check_LTImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
  "absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long long, long long>(unsigned long long, long long, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
  "absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long long, long long>(unsigned long long, long long, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
  "absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20230802::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long long, long long>(unsigned long long, long long, char const*) in proto_file.pb.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [qtui.app/Contents/MacOS/qtui] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qtui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Try to modify the absl lib, but there are more and more errors

final cmakelist:

```
find_package(absl CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message("pb include dir:${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set(absl_LIBRARIES
    absl::algorithm
    absl::base
    absl::debugging
    absl::flat_hash_map
    absl::flags
    absl::memory
    absl::meta
    absl::numeric
    absl::random_random
    absl::strings
    absl::synchronization
    absl::time
    absl::utility
    absl::log
)
message("absl: ${absl_LIBRARIES}")
```

cmake run log:

```
pb include dir:/opt/homebrew/include
absl: absl::algorithm;absl::base;absl::debugging;absl::flat_hash_map;absl::flags;absl::memory;absl::meta;absl::numeric;absl::random_random;absl::strings;absl::synchronization;absl::time;absl::utility;absl::log
```